# Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String: Hashmap

Tags: dictionary, hashmap

I am getting

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to String error at row number 19.

Can you tell me how to fix it.

```
package SAPPI;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HashMapExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map vehicles = new HashMap();

    // Add some vehicles.
    vehicles.put("BMW", 5);
    vehicles.put("Mercedes", 3);
    vehicles.put("Audi", 4);
    vehicles.put("Ford", 10);

    System.out.println("Total vehicles: " + vehicles.size());

    // Iterate over all vehicles, using the keySet method.
    for(String key: vehicles.keySet())
        System.out.println(key + " - " + vehicles.get(key));
    System.out.println();

    String searchKey = "Audi";
    if(vehicles.containsKey(searchKey))
        System.out.println("Found total " + vehicles.get(searchKey) + " "
                + searchKey + " cars!\n");

    // Clear all values.
    vehicles.clear();

    // Equals to zero.
    System.out.println("After clear operation, size: " + vehicles.size()); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In a nutshell, you should use [Java Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) (the same also applies if you are using C#).

Looking specifically at your code:

```
Map vehicles = new HashMap();
```

vehicles is a raw type. Therefore, when you use it like this:

```
for(String key: vehicles.keySet())
```

The compiler doesn't know that `keySet()` returns a set of strings. You can only declare your loop variable as `Object` here. If you had used generics (i.e. if you declared `vehicles` as a `Map<String>`, then the above would work.

Comment: Thanks. It helped.